# How to retrieve image from firebase storage by dialogflow chat bot?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, dialogflow-es

I need to retrieve image from firebase storage via my dialogflow chatbot google assistant. I already uploaded the image to storage and add the http link to firebase cloud database. If I ask "show my photo" to google assistant(test app), it should receive image response from firebase. I already enable webhook in dialogflow and using index.js file for coding.
Please help me to add code for image retrieving.
Fill up the code here

case 'photo.database':
    Please fill the code here.
break;

---

Existing code

---

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var firestore = admin.firestore();
// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
exports.MyInformation = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

console.log("request.body.result.parameters: ", 
request.body.result.parameters);
let params = request.body.result.parameters;

switch (request.body.result.action) {
case 'write.database':
firestore.collection(${params.name}).doc(${params.document}).set(params)
.then(() => {
if((params.name) === Riyas Elliyas){
response.send({
speech:Your database has been updated with ${params.document} - 
${params.content}
});
}
else{
response.send({
speech:Database of ${params.name} has been updated with ${params.document} - 
${params.content}
});
} 
})
.catch((e => {
console.log("error: ", e);
response.send({
speech: "something went wrong when writing on database"
});
}))
break;

case 'photo.database':
*** Imaging retrieving code is here ***
break;

default:
response.send({
speech: "no action matched in webhook"
});
}
});
```

Comment: I want to make sure I'm following the question correctly. You're doing this for the Google Assistant with Actions on Google, correct? How are you planning on displaying the image once you have it? You say you have the URL stored in the Firebase Database - do you know the path in the db where you have it stored? Is the question how to get that URL or how to get the image once you have the URL?

Comment: You're doing this for the Google Assistant with Actions on Google, correct? - Yes,  How are you planning on displaying the image once you have it? - Is there any special configuration need to display is google assistant? , do you know the path in the db where you have it stored? - Picture saved in firebase storage and copy the "download url" to database collection-document-filed"url". My question is - how to get the image once you have the URL?, i will pass http request from assistant to database with collection-document-filed name, then firebase should response with picture. Is it possible?